# Error in Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at CourseTest.main(CourseTest.java:11) in Java Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, error-handling

So currently I am studying Arrays so I am new to this. I have created this code but when I try to enter my inputs after specifying the size it gives me the error `java.lang.NullPointerException`
I know one of the ways is to use constructors but I want to try it this way.
Also I know my print statements are not configured correctly but I can fix that later should be simple.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
public class CourseTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of Course");
        int x=s.nextInt();
        Course arr[]=new Course[x];
        Course c =new Course();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Course Code");
            arr[i].setCchour(s.nextInt());
            System.out.println("Enter course Title");
            arr[i].setCtitle(s.next());
            System.out.println("Enter Course Credit hour");
            arr[i].setCchour(s.nextInt());
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Course Code is");
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            System.out.println("Course Title is");
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
            System.out.println("Course Credit hour is");
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}

"Class"
public class Course {

private int Ccode;
private String Ctitle;
private int Cchour;

public void setCcode(int Ccode) {
    this.Ccode = Ccode;
}

public void setCtitle(String Ctitle) {
    this.Ctitle = Ctitle;
}

public void setCchour(int Cchour) {
    this.Cchour = Cchour;
}

public int getCcode() {
    return Ccode;
}

public String getCtitle() {
    return Ctitle;
}

public int getCchour() {
    return Cchour;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

> `Course arr[]=new Course[x];`

Okay, you now have an array that can hold references (pointers) to course objects. It's like you've created a book where on each page you can write the details of a course, but the pages are still blank. It has `x` pages.

> `Course c =new Course();`

Okay, you have created a new course object, and you have created a new variable named `c` which can reference (point at) course objects; c now points at the created course.

You never use `c` again, so this line does nothing.

> `arr[i].setCchour(s.nextInt());`

okay, you flip to the first page of your book and,.. oh dear, it is blank, so, NullPointerException.

### Solution

learn about how java works, what references are. Then it becomes obvious: That `Course c = new Course();` line doesn't do anything; you want 1 course for *each* 'page' in your book-of-courses (your array), so `new Course()` needs to run x times. That suggests, correctly, that it needs be *inside* the for loop. First action in that for loop should be `arr[i] = new Course()`. Meaning: Create a new course object. Write the reference to this newly created object on the `i`-th page of your book of courses.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The way you explain is amazing and it helped to make it easy to understand